# Prove convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\log(n+2)}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I need to prove the convergence (pointwise, absolute and uniform) of the power serie $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\log(n+2)}$, what I know for now is using the Radio test with $c_n = \frac{1}{\log(n+2)}$ the result is $R=1$, so the series converge absolute (so pointwise) in $(-1,1)$ and uniformly in any compact $K \subset (-1,1)$, and there in no convergence in any apoint $\mathbb{R}\backslash[-1,1]$.

So what about the $-1$ and $1$ points? Is uniform convergence in $(-1,1)$? In the case, $-1$ and $1$ the series converge because it tends to zero, but I can' figure out another series to prove the uniform convergence with the Weierstrass-M test.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $x=-1$ you get an [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Conditional_convergence) $\sum_n(-1)^n\frac{1}{\log(n+2)}$. Since $\frac{1}{\log(n+2)}\searrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, the series converges (conditionally).

At $x=1$, since $0<\log(n+2)\leq n+2$, and $\sum_n\frac{1}{n+2}$ diverges to infinity, we get that $\sum_n\frac{1}{\log(n+2)}$ diverges to infinity too.

Comment: At $x = -1$, when you say as $n\rightarrow0$ do you mean as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @duster: fixed! thanks

Answer (score 2):

That series diverges when $x=1$ (since $n>1\implies\frac1{\log(n+2)}\geqslant\frac1n$) and converges when $x=-1$ (by the alternating series test).

Since it converges when $x=-1$, it follows from [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) that it converges uniformly on $[-1,0]$. Actually, it converges uniformly in $[-1,r]$ for any $r\in(0,1)$, but it does not converge uniformly in $[-1,1)$.

Comment: Is it true in general, that if a PS of positive coefficients with ROC 1 diverges at 1, then the convergence is not uniform on [-1,1)? This is not related to the question since you can just compare it with (x^n)/n, I'm asking in general.

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal That's not a good question, since the power series could diverge at $-1$. But, yes, if the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1)$, then it also converges at $1$.

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: Could you point me towards a proof of this?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal Why don't you post it as a question?

Comment: I don't know Latex